# Automatically add space after parenthesis in math mode if followed by certain characters

Tags: fonts, macros, conditionals, plain-tex, optex

I'm using plain TeX with the `luatex` engine (actually it is OpTeX, but you can just assume it is the "plain" luatex).  For my document I'm using the font EBGaramond. When I have a fomula like `$(f+g)$`, the letter f slightly overlaps the left parenthesis, and I don't like it.  Here is how I am triying to fix it, by adding some space in between the two characters.

```
\def \adef #1{\catcode`#1=13 \begingroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}


\edef\lp{(}
\adef({\futurelet\next\dolp}
\def\dolp{\lp\ifmmode\ifx\next f\mskip1.5mu\fi\fi}

Now there is some space between the parenthesis and the f, $(f+g)$.

\bye
```

I reported the macro `\adef` from OpTeX, which basically is equivalent to making the character active (in this case the parenthesis) and then defining it. This works, but I was wondering: is it the "proper" way to deal with this problem? Or should I make the fix in the font by adding some kernigs?  If so, how?

Regarding my solution, what if I want to add a space also for other letters? Suppose I have a list
`\def\list{fgj}` of characters (in this example the three characters f,g,j), how should I write the `\ifx` part so that it is true for any of the characters in `\list`?
What I unsuccessfully tried is

```
\def\dolp{\lp\ifmmode\ea\isinlist\ea\list\next\iftrue\mskip1.5mu\fi\fi}
```

where `\ea` is the OpTeX abbreviation for `\expandafter` and `\isinlist` is a OpTeX macro (you can look for it if needed).  I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean that best way is to give kerning exceptions for the Garamond-Math font. This is possible by following `\directlua` code:

```
\fontfam[garamond]

\directlua
  {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature 
    {
    name = "kerncorr",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
    ["("] = { [""] = 80, [""] = 50 },
    }
  }
}
\_def\_normalmath{%
    \_loadumathfamily 1 {[Garamond-Math]}{+kerncorr} % Base font
    \_loadmathfamily  4 rsfs              % script
    \_setunimathdimens
}%
\normalmath % we must reload Math font collection with {+kerncorr} again.

Test: $(f+g)$.

\bye
```

Note that the "f" and "g" at line 9 in the example above are not normal f and g. They are math italic f and g, Unicode U+1D453, U+1D454.

Comment: Thank you!  Just as additional curiosity, in the line of code where I use your `\isinlist` macro, do you know why it doesn't work?  With the expandfaters I try to expand first `\next`, but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: I have just noticed that your solution doesn't work in display mode.  Try `$$(f+g)$$`, please

Comment: Ad 1: `\next` is declared by `\futurelet`, so `\ea` has no effect to it and (of course) `\next` (this control sequence) is not in `\list`. Ad 2: I am not sure but is seems as a bug in the luaotfload implementation. There is no reason why display mode behaves differently. You can try to rewrite the example to pure luatex example (without OpTeX) and open an issue in luaotfload project at github.

Comment: 1. I didn't know that `\ea` has no effect on a control sequence declared by `\futurelet`. 
2. I don't know how to write it in pure luatex, so I can't open the issue

Comment: @User OK, try to show OpTeX minimal example at this github. I hope that guys there are very handy and they are able to convert this example to (say) LaTeX :).

Comment: Issue added :)  https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/174
It's already the second one in a month that I discovered and submitted. It seems like luaotfload has many bugs.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked luaotfload issue, kerning of `\mathopen` followed by `\mathord` noads is not supported in TeX's math layout. That it works in some cases related to inline math is a sideeffect which should not be relied upon.

Comment: OK, thanks. I added a notice about luatex engine in this issue. And workaround for this case of Garamond font: you can re-declare ``\Umathcode `( = 0 1 "28`` and ``\Umathcode `) = 0 1 "29``. The spacing is different in very special cases: `(=)` for example but kerning works.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using active character `(`. I tried to use math-only active character, i.e. `` \mathcode`(="8000 `` but this solution does not work in such constructions like `\bigl(`. So, global active `(` seems to be better:

```
\fontfam[garamond]

\adef({\string(\futurelet\next\addmkern}
\def\addmkern{\ifmmode\cs{mu:\meaning\next}\fi}

\sdef{mu:\meaning f}{\mkern1.5mu}
\sdef{mu:\meaning g}{\mkern1mu}

Test: $(f+g), (x)$, in text: (f).

\bye
```